# Send a variable from Chrome to VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, websocket, electron, vscode-extensions

I want to send a variable from Chrome, during a click event, and receive that variable in `VSCode`, through a `VSCode` extension.

The click event is not the problem. I'm struggling to receive data in `VSCode`.

[This](https://www.eliostruyf.com/callback-extension-vscode/) works, but I've only managed to get a delayed result from it (see below).

**Question:** In your opinion, which is the best solution?

I have added an answer with my solution.

##### **The delayed results from the example in the provided link:**

Suggested code:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const handleUri = (uri: vscode.Uri) => {
        // this doesn't log
        console.log('testing', uri);
        const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(uri.query);
        if (queryParams.has('say')) {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`URI Handler says: ${queryParams.get('say') as string}`);
        }
    };

    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.window.registerUriHandler({
          handleUri
        })
    );
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

However, only this example will log the desired result immediately:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const handleUri = (uri: vscode.Uri) => {
        // this doesn't log
        console.log('testing', uri);
        const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(uri.query);
        if (queryParams.has('say')) {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`URI Handler says: ${queryParams.get('say') as string}`);
        }
    };

    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.window.registerUriHandler({
          handleUri
        })
    );
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('my-org.myExtension', function () {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World');
        vscode.window.registerUriHandler({ handleUri })
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

In the first example above, the `handleUri` function is invoked as intended, but the logs are printed late (I had to invoke the command in the second example to see 'testing' and the `uri` logged).

Comment: redirect your click handler to url `vscode://eliostruyf.vscode-urihandler-test?say=How are you doing?` this should open VSCODE

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly, thanks, it does but I'm struggling to get that solution to show the variable. Even when I add my publisher and extension names to the `callback`. It opens VSCode though. I guess this would be a different SO question. Do you think this is the best solution?

Comment: URL encode the content of the variable in the `vscode:` URL you generate in the click handler

Comment: Thanks @rioV8, I certainly will, unfortunately it doesn't change the outcome yet. But agreed, this will be important.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that [this a good solution](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions#callbacks-and-uri-handlers), but not my chosen solution...

The downsides:

1. It will only open the link in the most recently used VSCode window; it won't send the data to each VSCode window, which might be a problem for your desired usage.
2. If you want to silently send the data from the browser through AJAX, you'll need to use a URI that starts with `vscode://`, which is not as easy to implement as `http://`.

So I made a simple server which was much easier.

In VSCode:

```
const vscode = require('vscode');
const handler = require('serve-handler');
const http = require('http');

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
function activate(context) {

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExtension.startServer', function () {
        // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed
        const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
            const headers = {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', /* @dev First, read about security */
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, POST, GET',
                'Access-Control-Max-Age': 2592000, // 30 days
                /** add other headers as per requirement */
            };
        
            if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
                res.writeHead(204, headers);
                res.end();
                return;
            }
        
            if (['GET', 'POST'].indexOf(req.method) > -1) {
                res.writeHead(200, headers);
                var url = new URL('http://localhost:6000' + req.url);
                var param = url.searchParams.get('param');
                console.log('Param: ', param)
                res.end('Hello World');
                return;
            }
        
            res.writeHead(405, headers);
            res.end(`${req.method} is not allowed for the request.`);


            // You pass two more arguments for config and middleware
            // More details here: https://github.com/vercel/serve-handler#options
            return handler(req, res);
        });
        
        server.listen(6000, () => {
            console.log('Running at http://localhost:6000');
        });

        // Display a message box to the user
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
function deactivate() {}
```

Then from the browser on the client side just make the `AJAX` request:

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/?param=1234' , {
  method: 'GET'
})
```

I hope this helps someone.